# Open URL from json array in Webview

Tags: android, json, android-activity, webview

I'm trying to open a URL in a webview in a different class from a URL that I've fetched in a JSONArray.

MainActivity class (I'm able to fetch the URL and display in a Toast message by using a getURL method I've created in my class that fetches the JSON and parses into an array)

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
   final Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WebViewActivity.class);
   progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   if (result == 1) {
      adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, feedsList);
      mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
      adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onItemClick(FeedItem item) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, item.getUrl(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // Here is what I've tried below but doesn't work
            String blogUrl = item.getUrl();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WebViewActivity.class);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(blogUrl));
            startActivity(intent);
         }
      });
   }
}
```

and here's my WebViewActivity class

```
public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   public WebView myWebView;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);
      String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
      myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
      myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
      WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
      webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      myWebView.loadUrl(url);
   }
}
```

What happens is when click the item in my RecyclerView it opens up the webview activity but just shows a blank screen, if I comment that out and only have the Toast message it shows the correct URL.  What am I doing wrong?

--Edit-- 
I have the activity defined in AndroidManifest as well

```
<activity
     android:name=".WebViewActivity"
     android:label="@string/title_activity_web_view"
     android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
     <meta-data
         android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
         android:value="com.mts2792.fishnews.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

Comment: Have you added internet permission to the manifest?

Comment: Yes I have, I added     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put url in the intent using `setData` and try to get it from intent in the second activity using `getStringExtra()`.

So, you should use `getData` in the second activity.

Comment: I don't see this to be the solution as it's already mentioned in the question that the correct URL displays when he puts it into a Toast.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I missed that.  I knew it had to be something simple.

Comment: @Jordan it actually worked, although it seems to be extremely slow to load the page which is a separate issue (I'm on Wi-FI and on a 1GB connection).

Comment: @Mitch Well congrats mate!